# can __sync_local_test_and_set/xchg be used to implement a mutex lock?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, locking

most search results for `__sync_local_test_and_set` are mentioning it can be used to implement a spinlock instead of a mutex lock.
The article [Multi-threaded programming: efficiency of locking](https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/multi-threaded-programming-efficiency-of-locking/) also reads: `I could not think of a means to implement mutex without closely interacting with the kernel(futex system call)` and also gives a example of implementing spinlock with `__sync_lock_test_and_set`.

But I think `__sync_lock_test_and_set` can also be used to implement a mutex lock:

```
if (__sync_lock_test_and_test(&lock, 1) == 0) { 
    // we get the lock, do our work
    lock = 0; // or __sync_lock_release(&lock);
} else {
    // the lock has already been token.
}
```

Does this work as a mutex lock?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `__sync_*` builtins are specific to the Linux kernel.  In other contexts you would want to use the C11 atomic types and functions from `<stdatomic.h>` (or C++11 `std::atomic` from `<atomic>`).

Your algorithm works, as far as it goes.  But the question is what goes in `// the lock has already been taken`.  What do you do in that block?  In most cases, the "work" you have to do isn't optional.  You can't just skip it; you have to wait and do it as soon as the lock is available.  In essence, what you've written is only the `trylock` and `unlock` functions of a typical mutex.  The harder one is `lock`.

You want to:

1. Wait for the mutex without consuming CPU
2. Wake up and take the mutex as soon as it becomes available, without unnecessary delay
3. If multiple threads are waiting for the mutex, arbitrate fairly between them, so that no one thread gets starved.

You can sort of accomplish #1 by doing something like

```
while (atomic_flag_test_and_set(&lock, 1) == 1) {
    thrd_yield(); 
    // or: thrd_sleep(short_time);
}
```

But you will still have the waiting thread waking up frequently, only to test the mutex, find it's still unavailable, and go back to sleep.  This may not consume much CPU time all told, but it does force a lot of unnecessary context switches, which is not free.

This doesn't do so great on #2, because when the mutex becomes available, this thread will not wake up to take it immediately; it will have to wait until it happens to get another time slice (in the case of `thrd_yield()`) or until its `short_time` expires.  This unnecessarily slows down your program.

And it doesn't accomplish #3 at all.  If several threads are waiting on the same mutex, it is basically random which one ends up taking it, and some may end up unfairly waiting much longer than others.

So you really need support from the OS to do `lock` properly.  The OS can create a queue of threads waiting on this particular mutex, and leave them asleep as long as it is unavailable.  When another thread unlocks the mutex, the OS can choose the oldest thread in the queue (or apply some other clever priority-based algorithm), wake up that thread and only that thread, and ensure that it does hold the mutex when it awakens.

Without OS support, you can't really do anything except a spinlock or some slightly glorified variant of it.

Comment: Re, "you really need support from the OS to do lock properly" That's true _unless_ you are willing to implement a complete system of [_green threads._](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_thread) If you implement green threads, then the "lock" operation works in user space exactly in the same way that it would work in kernel-space in an OS-provided implementation of threads: It would suspend the caller, and place the caller's saved context in a queue of threads that were awaiting the mutex, and the "unlock" operation would move waiting threads to the "ready-to-run" queue...

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Okay, in which case you need help from your userspace scheduler instead.  But either way, the atomic test-and-set operation isn't the whole solution.

Comment: Re, "userspace scheduler." Agreed. That "userspace scheduler" would be an essential part of a _complete system_ of green threads. I'm only arguing against one small point out of the many good points that comprise your answer. That is, your implication that it is impossible for user-space code to do scheduling. I've never seen a green-threads system with _preemptive_ scheduling, But I've seen several (including one that I created myself) that could create new threads, suspend them at known "yield points," and use a "scheduling policy" to choose which thread to resume next.